# Descarga de archivo Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy intentando que sólo los usuarios registrados puedan realizar la descarga de un libro y me encuentro con el problema de que el controlador responde bien la primera vez que se pulsa en "Descargar"(realiza la descarga y la añade a la base de datos). El problema viene al realizar otra descarga, se sigue bajando el archivo pero no añade más registros a la base de datos, incluso aunque modifique el controlador para que no devuelva nada o simplemente haga un 'echo' de cualquier cosa, me sigue bajando el archivo, digamos que está pillado en esa acción.

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo? Gracias.

**Vista**:  Envío el libro al controlador

```
@if (Auth::check())
          <div class="row">
           <div class="col-12">
            <a href="{{ route('downloadBook.userDownloadBook', $book->id) }}">  
            <img src="{!!asset('resourcesApp/pdf.png') !!}"></a>
           </div>
          </div>
@endif

**Contenido del enlace generado en la vista**:
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/downloadBook/userDownloadBook/48"> <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/resourcesApp/pdf.png"></a>
```

**Ruta controlador**:

```
Route::get('downloadBook/userDownloadBook/{idBook}', [DownloadBookController::class, 'userDownloadBook'])->name('downloadBook.userDownloadBook');
```

**Controlador**:

```
public function userDownloadBook($idBook)
    {
        $book= Book::find($idBook);
        $params=["book_id"=>$idBook,"user_id"=> Auth::user()->id];
         Download::create($params);
         return response()->download("$book->download_link");

//$book->download_link muestra en la BD la ruta del libro a descargar "storage/ebooks/NombreLibro.pdf"
    }
```

Comment: El código mínimo para un  [mcve] va como texto

Comment: @BetaM gracias!

Comment: prueba limpiando la caché de Laravel. Si es una versión superior a la versión 7 puedes hacer: `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: @gaidyjg sigue igual, gracias de todas maneras

Comment: Podrías mostrar el html que te genera el código de la vista (puedes hacer click derecho e inspeccionar elemento). También sería útil que muestres la ruta `downloadBook.download` y el valor de `public_path("$book->download_link")`. Además... ¿estás seguro de que no tienes otro link directamente al archivo?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ he modificado algunas cosas y de vez en cuando después de recargar y descargar va añadiendo alguna descarga a la BD. Actualizo con el código que me has dicho a ver si aclara algo. Muchas gracias !

Comment: Lo que mustras se ve bien. Es raro que no inserteen la BD sin lanzar algún error

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ tiene que ser algo con response(),  cuando lo quito y después de reiniciar etc consigo que salga del 'bucle', cada vez que le doy al enlace introduce una nueva descargas a la BD.

Comment: Te diría que pruebes con `return Storage::download($book->download_link);` pero en BD guardaste el nombre del archivo con un path que no es el convencional.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Ya lo he solucionado, probando desde Storage::download y modificando la ruta que guardo en la BD. Muchas gracias